# Application does not exit after Exception is thrown

Tags: c#, exception

I have unusual (for me) problem with thrown exception. After exception is thrown application loops on it and doesn't exit.

```
if(!foundRemoteID)
{
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
          "value",
          "Remote ID was not found."
          );
}
```

I have inserted brakepoint on "if(!foundRemoteID)" line but the program doesn't hit it at all after firs thrown exception. It just loops over and over on "throw new (..).

-I do not have try{} catch{} blocks at all at any level.
-There is no loop that contains this code

I have even tried putting it into:

```
try
{
(..)
}
finally
{
Enviroment.Exit(1);
}
```

but finally{} block is never hit.

Other throw new (..) in this class is acting same way.

Am I missing something trivial?

UPDATE:
Problem is not related to my project. I have just created a simple console application that has only

```
throw new FileNotFoundException();
```

In Main() method and problem persists.

I have already tried resetting VS2010 settings to default and it didn't help.

Comment: How are you determining that it loops? Are you running this from within the Visual Studio debugger?

Comment: It might be that you have some pending finalizers that must run afterward, causing this to happen!!

Comment: Toggle a breakpoint in the `throw` line and check call stack for any recursive call in your code. If no loop is wrapping your code, then must be a non-controlled recursive call.

Comment: Can you post some more code (the code before the if statement)? so it will be possible to tell you the correct problem that causing it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely this is not the actual behavior of your application - rather, Visual Studio is set to always break when there is an unhandled ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

You can verify this by pressing "Start without debugging".

If you want to change the settings, browse to the menu to Debug -> Exceptions and you should see the following.  Then uncheck "User-unhandled."

Personally, I recommend leaving the setting the way it is in most cases.  It really helps when hunting down unhandled exceptions.

[image: Visual Studio Debug Exceptions]

Comment: Setting are in default. Application run without debugging (in Service mode) also returns exception and continues to work.

Comment: Ok, so this explains why your debugger gets stuck on that line, but you still have the issue of your application still running after the exception occurs.  It's possible that somewhere in your code, the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event handler was assigned to a method which is eating your exception.

Comment: If have looked all over the project (also in settings) but didn't found anything like that. Normal exceptions (not thrown by me) are working correctly by shutting down the application.

Comment: Try the directions I suggested in the answer, and then use the debugger to step past the line that throws the exception to see where the code is going.

Comment: I was already using "Step over" but it went straight to exception again. I have created new console application and inserted just "throw new (..)" and same thing happened. It must be something in my VS2010 configuration. If I find something I'll surely post it down here. However I wouldn't like to resort to "Reset to default". EDIT: I have just use Reset to Default option and problem persists. That is going to be a long night.....

Comment: Also when I run stuff like "int a = 1/0" it also gets stuck on exception. Now I'm desperate.

Comment: The default settings are causing you to get stuck on these exceptions.  Please re-read the answer I posted and try it.

Comment: Thanks! It might be just to much work or night time but I may bet my life that I have unchecked all check boxes that I could in that window. I did it for like 5 more times and it worked. I have restarted VS2010 after doing so too but I guess I have missed something every time. Thanks again! Unexpectedly I will sleep tonight.